# Get URL from a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm developing an iOS Application. I'm using UIWebView to allow users to search for all kind of clip or video.
Everything works, Now I'm trying to inject Javascript code into UIWebView to get video url played by the native iOS player which starts after tapping preview placed in UIWebView.
I'm not sure about this kind of approach because I'm able to get the URL where preview is placed (the main HTML page) instead of the right movie url.
Here my code:

JS Function

```
//JSTools.js
function getURL() {
    var e = document.location.href;
    return e;
}
```

Here my method implementation into Objective-C class:

```
//handle player - viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

-(void)videoStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // your code here
    NSLog(@"call");
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JSTools" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];
    NSString *url = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getURL();"];
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
```

Hope someone will help. Thank you in advance. Giacomo

Comment: Did you find any solution for this Giacomo ?

Comment: Hi Vishnu, unfortunately I didn't! :(